# What's the cheapest way to store an auto increment indexed list of values in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora, elastic-cache

I have a DynamoDB-based web application that uses DynamoDB to store my large JSON objects and perform simple CRUD operations on them via a web API. I would like to add a new table that acts like a categorization of these values. The user should be able to select from a selection box which category the object belongs to. If a desirable category does not exist, the user should be able to create a new category specifying a name which will be available to other objects in the future.

It is critical to the application that every one of these categories be given a integer ID that increments starting the first at 1. These numbers that are auto generated will turn into reproducible serial numbers for back end reports that will not use the user-visible text name.

So I would like to have a simple API available from the web fronted that allows me to:

A) GET /category : produces { int : string, ... } of all categories mapped to an ID

B) PUSH /category : accepts string and stores the string to the next integer

Here are some ideas for how to handle this kind of project.

1. Store it in DynamoDB with integer indexes. This leaves has some benefits but it leaves a lot to be desired. Firstly, there's no auto incrementing ID in DynamoDB, but I could definitely get the state of the table, create a new ID, and store the result. This might have issues with consistency and race conditions but there's probably a way to achieve this safely. It might, however, be a big anti pattern to use DynamoDB this way.
2. Store it in DynamoDB as one object in a table with some random index. Just store the mapping as a JSON object. This really forgets the notion of tables in DynamoDB and uses it as a simple file. It might also run into some issues with race conditions.
3. Use AWS ElasticCache to have a Redis key value store. This might be "the right" decision but the downside is that ElasticCache is an always on DB offering where you pay per hour. For a low-traffic web site like mine I'd be paying minumum $12/mo I think and I would really like for this to be pay per access/update due to the low volume. I'm not sure there's an auto increment feature for Redis built in the way I'd need it. But it's pretty trivial to make a trasaction that gets the length of the table, adds one, and stores a new value. Race conditions are easily avoid with this solution.
4. Use a SQL database like AWS Aurora or MYSQL. Well this has the same upsides as Redis, but it's also more overkill than Redis is, and also it costs a lot more and it's still always on.
5. Run my own in memory web service or MongoDB etc... still you're paying for constant containers running. Writing my own thing is obviously silly but I'm sure there are services that match this issue perfectly but they'd all require a constant container to run.

Is there a food way to just store a simple list, or integer mapping like this that doesn't cost a constant monthly cost? Is there a better way to do this with DynamoDB?

Comment: You could create a separate table in DynamoDB that just stores the next auto increment integer value, and use DynamoDB atomic counters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters

Comment: How many requests per second must be supported?

Comment: Requests per second would be pretty low. I think I've never seen more than 4 requests per second and generally the app is not in use. But I do need it to be always available. That's not to say I don't hope to scale it.

Answer (score 1):

Store the `maxCounterValue` as an item in DyanamoDB.
For the PUSH /category, perform the following:

1. Get the current `maxCounterValue`.
2. TransactWrite:

   1. Put the category `name` and `id` into a new item with `id = maxCounterValue + 1`.
   2. Update the `maxCounterValue +1`, add a ConditionExpression to check that `maxCounterValue = :valueFromGetOperation`.
3. If TransactWrite fails, start at 1 again, try X more times